# How to debug specific SQL occasionally result in BigQuery "Request timed out. Please try again"

Tags: google-bigquery

In the last week or so a subset (single digit out of thousands per day) of the SQL we submit to BigQuery in interactive mode started to take hours instead of seconds. The SQL for the jobs that timed out appeared to very specific cases. I was able to reproduce the behavior with these two jobs from the BigQuery console:

The working invocation (ran in 5 secs):

```
Job ID  bluecore-qa:US.bquijob_4e0e4662_1639a278fcf
Creation Time   May 25, 2018, 9:54:34 PM
Start Time  May 25, 2018, 9:54:34 PM
End Time    May 25, 2018, 9:54:39 PM
Bytes Processed 176 MB
Bytes Billed    177 MB
Slot Time (ms)  271 K
```

The exact same SQL (ran less than a minute later) that timed out after 6 hours:

```
Job ID  bluecore-qa:US.bquijob_57c799e2_1639a2852fa
Creation Time   May 25, 2018, 9:55:24 PM
Start Time  May 25, 2018, 9:55:24 PM
Query Priority  Interactive

Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration       User Email       Bytes Processed   Bytes Billed   Billing Tier   Labels
---------- --------- ----------------- ---------- --------------------- ----------------- -------------- -------------- --------
query      FAILURE   25 May 21:55:24   5:59:45    xxxxx
Error encountered during job execution:
Request timed out. Please try again.
```

Note that the SQL does use 'IGNORE CASE' which has been problematic for us in the past (but usually resulting in an 'internal error' case).

Is there a way to get more information on the job to see whether the 2nd job got pushed back in the BigQuery scheduling queue? 
(According to BigQuery StackDriver stats we stay well under the 2000 slot limit for our project).

Comment: I would suggest [filing a bug report](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=0) with a link to this post and a sample job ID.

Comment: Thanks Elliott, done: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80407917

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a Google BigQuery side issue. They are working on a fix and will update https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/80407917 once this is out.

Answer (score 0):

In BigQuery, jobs never pushed back to the BigQuery scheduling queue (even in streaming and interactive modes).

You can use [Audit logs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/audit-logs) to get more details about the timeouts. Audit logging is currently the only alternative available for the Stackdriver.

Comment: Thanks Shahin, Audit logs don't show more than the "Request timed out. Please try again" message on completion unfortunately.

Comment: There are only these two tools are available for BigQuery clients. After checking your logs, I am sure that it is related to an internal issue on the Google side.